# Can't load module models in node js

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I have the following structure for node js
App

```
 |-node_modules  
 |-src
    -models
    -service
    -utils
    -views
    -router
    -app.js
    -index.js
```

Inside service, there is service there is .js file.
Error: Cannot find module '../models

I am trying to load models like this

I tried looking up many examples but didn't find the root cause.

> var models = require("../models);

How to load models successfully... surprisingly I am able to load utils from the same service class.

---

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var EventsCalendar = sequelize.define("EventsCalendar", {
    eventId: { type: DataTypes.STRING(10), allowNull: false,primaryKey: true },
    eventDate : { type: DataTypes.DATE , allowNull: false },
  });

  EventsCalendar.associate = (models) => {
    EventsCalendar.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as :"user"
    });
  };

  return EventsCalendar;
};
```

Comment: did you export your models

Comment: `../models` is for directory, `./models` is for a file

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I am trying to load directory. It has model classes

Comment: @prisar Yes. I added  a file for your reference

Comment: Are you sure loading multiple files from a directory in one `require` call is supported at all?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am not sure. I am totally new to node.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a file with the syntax `require("../models")` for this reason you get the error `Cannot find module '../models`. 
If you create the models.js file in the upperscope (due the `../`) all will works.

In any case you can:

- load a file: `require('./myfile')`
- load an `index.js` file in a directory: `require('./my-directory/')`
- load a file in a directory: `require('./my-directory/myfile')`
- load a file in a directory using relative path: `require('../../my-parent-dir/myfile')`

You should read the official doc as a reference to understand [how modules are loaded](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Comment: The behaviour is wired. Some files load and some others don't even though the path is correct. Also, can't I load the entire module?

Comment: If you mean "all the files in a directory", yes, it is possible but you need a package that does this for you like [`require-dir`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir). If you are looking for a core method that loads the folder, there is not this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `db.js` file in the same folder where `package.json` file exists.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const db = {};
const config = require('./config');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: config.host,
    database: config.databaseName,
    username: config.username,
    password: config.password,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
      timestamps: false
    },
    pool: {
      max: 100,
      min: 10,
      idle: 200000,
      acquire: 1000000
    }
  });

  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });


  fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname + '/models')
    .filter(file =>
      (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
      (file !== basename) &&
      (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
    .forEach(file => {
      const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, 'models/' + file));
      db[model.name] = model;
    });

  Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });

  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = Sequelize;


  module.exports = { db };
```

After that in particular service import all models from `db.js` like this.

```
const { db } = require("./../db");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had written as

```
 module.export
```

It should have been `module.exports`

After changing I was able to import.